# How to migrate db from mysql to db2

Tags: db2, database-migration

I want to migrate Database from mysql to Db2.

I need to do it using CLP and also without any tool. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IBM Data Movement Tool.

Follow the directions in [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/).

If you really want to do it without the tool (I don't recommend this) then at a minimum you'll need to:

- create storage in db2 (databases, tablespaces, etc.) that match your mysql database
- look at your tables and translate any column types from their mysql types to DB2 types
- make sure you recreate any indexes, key contraints, triggers
- translate any other stored procedures and other database objects

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0606khatri/) has some information on data mapping to mysql.